# how can i upload multiple images to s3 using vuejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, amazon-s3

how can i upload multiple images to amazon s3

this is my middleware for image upload

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");

aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWSSecretKey,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWSAccessKeyId
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();

const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'ajibade',
        acl: 'public-read',
        metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
        },
        key: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, Date.now().toString())
        }
    })
})

module.exports = upload;
```

this is how i upload the file

```
<label class="choosefile-button">
                    
                    <input
                      type="file"
                      @change="onFileSelected1"
                    >
                    <p style="margin-top: -70px">{{ fileName }}</p>
                  </label>
                  
                   <label class="choosefile-button">
            
                    <input
                      type="file"
                      @change="onFileSelected2"
                    >
                    <p style="margin-top: -70px">{{ fileName }}</p>
                  </label>
```

how i call the function

```
methods: {
    onFileSelected1(event) {
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
      console.log(this.selectedFile)
      this.fileName = event.target.files[0].name
    },
      onFileSelected2(event) {
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
      console.log(this.selectedFile)
      this.fileName = event.target.files[0].name
    },
    }
```

each time i click on either onFileSelected1 or onFileSeleted2 it uploads the same images for the both inputs

this is my post request

```
router.post(`/products`, upload.single("photo"), async (req, res) => {
  console.log(res);
  try {
    let product = new Product();
    product.photo = req.file.location;
    await product.save();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
   
  }
});
```

please how can i go about this

Comment: What does your frontend upload function look like?

Comment: @AnonymousUser it's in the question check methods

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](https://www.concentrationcode.com/uploading-vue/) explains quite in depth how it's done.

Basically what you need to do is add a `<input type="file" multiple />` and in your upload function turn it into multipart/form-data. Then when you upload it to your backend, you use multer and multer-s3 to send it to S3.

I think you've mixed up a few concepts here, your upload function looks like a route that is supposed to be in the backend of the application, where you then send the request to upload files using for example axios or the fetch API.